# IPhone - UIImage to Binary String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have this bit of code that get the image i have picked from the Camera and displays it into a UIImageView. I want to convert the image to a binary string so i can then make a URL call and pass it back to the server. How would I modify this code to get my binary string?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    imageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better pass the NSData got from image jpeg representation to the server by POST method.

Marco

Comment: To get data from your image:

myImageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage,compressionQuality);
//compressionQuality range from 0.0 (worst quality) to 1.0(best quality)

Here is how to use POST method:http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/21645-using-post-method.html

Marco

Answer (score -1):

You can find an example of how to do it from Apple in [this technote](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html).  Not as easy as it should be, but appears that it's the only way to do it.  Is it possible for you to get the data before it becomes a `UIImage` to make your life a little easier?  If not, just try the method presented at the link.

Comment: He doesn't need the raw bitmap data.

Comment: How do we know?  I don't think he said.

Comment: Guys, My Goal is to transfer the image taken to a server via a http Post so not sure it I would need the RAW or not??

Comment: Because he doesn't need to manipulate the image pixel by pixel, so it's a waste of memory. It's also e waste of internet connection to send the pixels data.

Comment: MartGriff, follow the hint i gave you.